# java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host. while replacing fragment

Tags: android

I try to replace one fragment by another and get this error. I updated all libraries to latest version, but looks like I have mistake in the code while probably I don't understand something...

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host.
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:321)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:286)
```

call from parent adapter feed:

```
    private void clickId (View v, String idAuthor) {
    new PrivateMessageShow();
    }
```

class PrivateMessageShow

```
public class  PrivateMessageShow extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public PrivateMessageShow () {
       fragmentManager =  getSupportFragmentManager();
       fragmentTransaction =   fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
       fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.navigation_privateconversation, new PrivateMessageFragment(), "tag");
       fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
       fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Class PrivateMessageFragment which fails:

```
public class PrivateMessageFragment extends Fragment {

 RecyclerView recyclerView;

 public PrivateMessageFragment() {
 
 }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_private_message, container, false);

        final Context mycontext = getActivity();
        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPrivateMessage);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mycontext);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just move your fragment transaction code from the constructor to `onCreate` method. You got the error because the fragment manager did not have a host (activity) yet when you called it from the constructor. You can learn more about activity and fragment on https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 2):

You need to call fragment transaction code in Activity's onCreate method

Rename constructor, keep it as a method as below -

```
 public void loadFragment () {
   fragmentManager =  getSupportFragmentManager();
   fragmentTransaction =   fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.navigation_privateconversation, new 
   PrivateMessageFragment(), "tag");
   fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Call this method in onCreate of PrivateMessageShow acitivity.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, error disappeared, but method is not executed (onCreate not executed). I did something wrong? @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Logger.logowanie("Private Message Show onCreate");
        loadFragment();

    }

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked for you, And also share the code of your fragment activity with attached xml

Comment: code does not generate error, but onCreate which replaced cursor is not executed, so fragment does not change

Comment: This is another step, The problem that you described is resolved I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I called
`fragmentManager =  getSupportFragmentManager(); and ...` in onCreate method and before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` but the correct way must be AFTER `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    //Other fratment Operations goes here
}
```